# Call to undefined method CI_Controller::Controller()

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have got this controller:

```
    class Start extends CI_Controller{
   var    $base;
   var    $css;

   function Start()
   {
       parent::Controller(); //error here.
       $this->base = $this->config->item('base_url'); //error here
       $this->css = $this->config->item('css');   

   }

  function hello($name)
  {
    $data['css'] = $this->css;
    $data['base'] = $this->base;
    $data['mytitle'] = 'Welcome to this site';
    $data['mytext'] = "Hello, $name, now we're getting dynamic!";
    $this->load->view('testView', $data);
   }
}
```

it tells me in this line:

parent::Controller(); //error here.

```
 Call to undefined method CI_Controller::Controller()
```

If I remove that line..I get an error for the next line that says..

```
Call to a member function item() on a non-object
```

How do I prevent such errors form happening?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're using CI 2.x then your class constructor should look like this:

```
   public function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code
   }
```

read more in [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#constructors)

Answer (score 3):

In CodeIgniter 2, the constructor is named `__constructor` and not the class name. So you need to call `parent::__construct()` instead of `parent::Controller()`

Here's an article that you can read that shows one major difference between CodeIgniter 1.x and CodeIgniter 2.x

http://ulyssesonline.com/2011/03/01/differences-between-codeigniter-1-7-2-and-2-0-0/

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your Codeigniter project via Xampp or a similar server add the following code to the bottom of your config.php file in the following directory; ci_project/application/config/config.php

```
function my_load($class) {        

    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0) {            
        if (is_readable(APPPATH . 'core' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class . '.php' )) {                
            require_once (APPPATH . 'core' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class . '.php');                
        }
    }

}

spl_autoload_register('my_load');
```

The above code would help to; load class in core folder.
I'm certain this works in the following setup; CI-3+, Xampp, Php5.6, and or 5.6+

Also, you can then decide to create and allow other classes to reference your own Controller (which extends the original CI_Controller) by creating a file named MY_Controller.php in the following directory: ci_project/application/core/ and adding the following code in it;

```
<?php
    class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    }
?>
```

That way you can always just reference or extend the other Classes to your own Controller (MY_Controller) throughout the rest of the project e.g.

```
class Admin extends MY_Controller {
    //your function here
}
```

I hope this helps.